# Domain rational function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If  $k=5 $ and $ a<0 $. Find the domain of the function:

$ f(x)= \dfrac{3x-5}{\sqrt{2x^2+5ax}} $

This is my progress:

$ 2x^2+5ax>0 $ 
$ x(2x+5a) >0 $ 
$ x>0 $ or $ x>\dfrac{-5a}{2}  $

I need a good recommendation to do the analysis on the number line, the exercise is a bit confusing for me

Answer (score 2):

$xy >0$ iff ($x>0$ **and** $y >0$) OR ($x<0$ **and** $y <0$). So we need $x>0$ and $x>-\frac {5a}2$ or $x<0$ and $x <-\frac {5a}2$ Since $a<0$ this reduces to $x \in (-\infty ,0) \cup (-\frac {5a}2 ,\infty)$.

Comment: Is this a definition? @Kavi Rama Murthy

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the case $x<0, x<\dfrac{-5a}{2}$

We know that multiplying two number with like sign gives us a positive number or $>0$ number. So we can say

- if both are positive

$x>0, x>\dfrac{-5a}{2}$

- if both are negative

$x<0, x<\dfrac{-5a}{2}$

Comment: Is this a definition? @Jitendra Singh

Comment: Can you more specific? I don't know what is NCERT @Jitendra Singh

Comment: @JasonAndres yes it is a definition

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x) = x(2x+5a)$. $f$ has roots at $x=0$ and $x=\frac{-5a}2 > 0$. It is a convex quadratic curve.

Do a quick sketch of the  curve:

[image]

and we can see that $x < 0$ or $x > \frac{-5a}2$